# middleman active tag and year and tag cloud

Tags: ruby, tags, cloud, liquid, middleman

i convert my page from liquidluck to middleman and all what need is complete. Only the tag and year cloud i find not really information to finished this setup. Yet all tags and the year from the article is highlight in cloud. This option come from liquid when understand correct. But i find not information about Ruby Erb to convert this part in middleman.

```
{% block aside %}
<aside class="blog">
  <ul>
    {% for year, posts in resource.year.iteritems()|reverse %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ content_url(site.prefix, year, 'index.html') }}"{% if year ==  post.date.year %} class="active"{% endif %}>
        {{ year }}
        <span>{{ posts|length }}</span></a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <ul> 
    {% for tag, posts in resource.tag.iteritems()|sort %}
      <li><a href="{{ tag|tag_url }}"{% if tag in post.tags %} class="active"{% endif %}>{{ tag }}<span>{{ posts|length }}</span></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</aside>
{% endblock %}
```

Has someone a advice to convert this part?

Thank you for help & Nice Day
Silvio